# How do I add code to remove the .php from the .htaccess file when I already have a redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I already have code to add the https ... so how do I remove the .php from the end of the url as well? This is what my code looks like so far.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I also want to add the `www` to the front of the url ... e.g. `https://www.google.com`

Comment: sounds like a dupe

Comment: Use Nginx, far more advanced as (I am guessing) Apache. Also Nginx is way faster and more reliable. To my opinion at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove .php like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index    index.php
```

Then you need to call `www.example.com/index` instead of `www.example.com/index.php`